# Why is a tetrahedron used in the derivation of Cauchy's stress formula

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

After looking at the derivation of Cauchy's stress formula, stated as:

$$ \vec{t} = \sigma \hat{n} $$

I've reflected upon the derivation and some questions have arised. I state them below:

- First of all, why are we using tetrahedrons in our derivation? Are we limited to this geometric shape, or is it just because it's easier in the sense that it's the three dimensional shape with least sides (at least what I can imagine myself)? Implying that we have less terms to work with.

[image]

- Secondly, would we arrive at the same result if we instead used cubes for instance? If anyone could provide any link / or any proof themselves, that would arrive at the same result with another geometric shape, that'd be really enough to convince me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even Wiki seems to be doing the cube. A tetrahedron is just the simplest in a certain sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A tetrahedron allows you to select a plane of arbitrary orientation relative to your coordinate directions to determine the traction vector on an arbitrary plane.  That is what the Cauchy stress relation calls for.  You don't use cubes because these won't permit you to consider a plane of arbitrary orientation.

Comment: Ohh now I see why the tetrahedron is useful, however, I still don't understand your last sentence. Why won't that permit us to consider a plane of arbitrary orientation, couldn't we just use cubes rotated in 3D space to get any arbitrary orientation of the plane? Or am I missing something important here?

Comment: Try that and see how it works out for you.

Comment: Indeed, one would do some arbitrary cube rotation, and then settle on looking at some tetrahedral bit relative to your axes.

Comment: I'm sorry Chet Miller, but I do not like your answer at all and I totally support @Tanamas comment. I'm doing Ph.D. in fluid mechanics and can firsthand witness your definition is what is given to the students at universities in at least two parts of the Globe (where I have had studied). That definition is absolutely not intelligible. No wonder nobody understands it, gets used to it with time and gets impression that he understands it. Tanamas, do not think of the tetrahedron. Think of the plane. The plane is such a common trick in the physics of continuum matter. The trick is the following.

Comment: You want to find forces in a continuum media (fluid in our case). You imagine you cut the media with a knife, move the two parts apart, use the 3rd Newton's law to say that the two parts are attracted to each other with the same forces, those forces - therefore - the forces acting with the fluid and we can consider one part to work with those forces. When you cut the fluid with a knife, you've got a planar cut. That is why you're considering a plane. You cut arbitrary (to consider a general case). That's why the plane has "arbitrary orientation". Now, here's where the tetrahedron comes from.

Comment: You applied a force to the plane. It is a general thing in physics to break the force vector on the components along the axes. Your original force acts on your arbitrary plane. You've got components of the force along x, y, z. Those components - by analogy - must also act on some planes. What planes? Force along x must act on the plane perpendicular to x. The same is for y and z components. You just draw those planes along with your original "arbitrary" plane and get your tetrahedron.

Comment: Regarding to the use of cubes, I would disagree with Chet Miller. You can use them. And we use them in the introductory fluid mechanics course because they are way more intuitive and intelligible then "arbitrary" planes leading to the tetrahedrons. The rigorous justification for the cubes can be very difficult, though not impossible. Non rigorous justification for the cubes is way easier than for tetrahedrons.

Comment: @IvanNepomnyashchikh Ohhh that makes alot of sense! I always thought they just picked the tetrahedron as an arbitrary geometry. However, the procedure you described where you first make a planar cut, and then decompose it onto the different components, makes it very obvious as to why they arise at a tetrahedron. Thank you very much for your explanation, it was very thorough and easy to understand.

Comment: I thought that this is pretty much just what my answer said.l. It never occurred to me that people would have trouble realizing where the other 3 faces of the tetrahedron come from.